# Watir-webdriver FileField clears after tab away from Element

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver

We're writing a really pedantic Watir-webdriver/Cucumber test that tests the tab order on the page. As part of this, we tab into a FileField, attach a file, then tab to the next element. This works as expected when done manually.

However, when we do this with Watir-webdriver, the element is becoming unset when we tab to the next element. The process is basically to use the `#set` method on the FileField element (and at this point the field does in fact list the filename), then I tab to the next element by using `browser.send_keys :tab`.

This seems to be the proper way to do it from everything I've read, but once that tab is sent the field clears. Any idea what's up?

I'm doing this using jRuby and the Firefox driver on a Mac running Mountain Lion, if that helps.

Comment: So, there is text in a given and it stays there when you tab manually, but when you use Watir the :tab goes to the field and clears out the text?

Comment: I was able to reproduce the same issue. Seems like a bug to me (likely in Selenium rather than Watir). Though if you are testing the tab order, why not just tab through all the fields without inputting them?

Comment: It seems like I can't tab out of the file field either, so I'd definitely say it's a bug. Thanks for looking into it!